# How to show disabled state for a jqueryui button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I am using Jquery UI buttons (http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/). I would like to know how I can show a disabled state. Show the button as greyed out or something, you know how when you post a form on some sites the submit button shows as disabled.

Also is there anyway to display an active state???

This is my code:

```
 $(".commentsbutton").button({icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-comment'}}); 

<a href="javascript:void[0]">Comments</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the button via the [`disable` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-disable), like this:

```
$(".commentsbutton").button("disable");​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ce55b/1/), to re-enable later, just use the `enable` method, like this:

```
$(".commentsbutton").button("enable");​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Cheers nick. It works but when I put it inside the function that submits the form it doesn't: 
 
$("form#microblogpost").submit(function() {
  
  $("#messagesubmitbutton").button("disable"); 

the #messagesubmitbutton is within the form I am submitting could this affect it???

Comment: @user342391 - Is the form being replaced via AJAX? (also make sure not to use element names on ID selectors, `#microblogpost` (without `form`) is much faster).  Is this button an anchor, a `<button>` or....?

Comment: Form isn't being replaced via ajax but other elements are when form post is successful. This is the button code:

<button style="float:right" id="messagesubmitbutton" class="triangleeastbutton">Microblog it</button>

Comment: @user342391 - Are there many of these buttons in the page, or are the IDs being used unique?

Comment: I have pasted the full code above. ID is unique, even changed it to something obscure to be sure.

Comment: @user342391 - I don't see in your code where you're calling `.button()` like in the original question...does this look like a normal button or a jQuery UI button?

Comment: Sorry here it is:  $(".triangleeastbutton").button({icons: { secondary: 'ui-icon-circle-triangle-e'}});

Comment: It was running in a separate file. Just moved it. See above. Still same issue

Comment: @user342391 - There's nothing standing out at me here, where is `#microblogposts` at, and do you have a link to a site I can see this happening on?

Comment: Thanks for the help Nick. You found the problem. #microblogposts contained links to the Jquery files. Removed them and WORKING!!! Cool cheers mate